# Canvas.drawText: Problem with EmojiCompat (Android - Java)

Tags: android

In my app I use the EmojiCompat.get().process(myCharSequence) function to be able to view the new emojis not installed on the device.
Everything works perfectly when, for example when I add the items in the NavigationView menu or in a spinner:

`nvMenu.add(Menu.NONE, userIdList[i], Menu.NONE, EmojiCompat.get().process(myCharSequence));`
[NavigationView example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTcWI.png)

The problem comes out when I use the canvas.drawText function.
In the same place in the app everything works perfectly if I use the Toast function.  (see images)[canvas and toast examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UojRC.png)

```
Toast.makeText(myContext, EmojiCompat.get().process(myCharSequence), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
canvas.drawText(EmojiCompat.get().process(myCharSequence), 0, myText.length(), x, y, paintText);
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks to those who want to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Result of `EmojiCompat.get().process(myCharSequence)` will return a `Spanned` object, which may have one or more `EmojiSpan` objects in it. `EmojiSpan` has method `draw (Canvas canvas,...)`, which you should use to display the content of those intervals of your string and you should use a regular `drawText` for everything in-between. Something like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19 && EmojiCompat.get().getLoadState()==EmojiCompat.LOAD_STATE_SUCCEEDED)
{
  CharSequence processed=EmojiCompat.get().process(str);
  if(processed instanceof Spanned)
  {
    EmojiSpan[] spans=((Spanned)processed).getSpans(0,processed.length(),EmojiSpan.class);
    if(spans!=null && spans.length>0)
    { 
      float xx=x;
      canvas.drawText(str.substring(0,((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[0])),xx,y,paint);
      xx+=paint.measureText(str.substring(0,((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[0])));
      for(int i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
      {
        spans[i].draw(canvas,processed,((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[i]),((Spanned)processed).getSpanEnd(spans[i]),xx,(int)(y+fontMetrics.top),(int)y,(int)(y+fontMetrics.bottom),paint);
        xx+=spans[i].getSize(paint,processed,((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[i]),((Spanned)processed).getSpanEnd(spans[i]),paint.getFontMetricsInt());
        canvas.drawText(processed.subSequence(((Spanned)processed).getSpanEnd(spans[i]),i+1<spans.length ? ((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[i+1]) : processed.length()).toString(),xx,y,paint);
        xx+=paint.measureText(processed.subSequence(((Spanned)processed).getSpanEnd(spans[i]),i+1<spans.length ? ((Spanned)processed).getSpanStart(spans[i+1]) : processed.length()).toString());
      }
      return;
    }
  }
}
canvas.drawText(str,x,y,paint);
```

**Note** this code needs adjustment for RTL languages.